# What does standalone operator * do at beginning of an equation in C++?

Tags: c++, operators

I'm going through some code and came across a line like:

`x = * y`

What is the asterisk (`*`) in this case?  I have some programming knowledge, but I'm new to C++. I think I grasp the concept of pointer variables, but the order and spaces make me think it's different than the `*=` operator or `*y` pointer.

Comment: It dereferences the pointer `y`. Whitespace between `y` and `*` is not important.

Comment: This is not an equation. This is an assignment. This is a significant difference. It has nothing to do with the mathematics concept of an equation.

Comment: You could write `x = -         y;` as well, if `x` and `y` are e.g. numbers and the number of space chars between the `-` and `y` doesn't change the fact that the unary `-` operator is used...

Comment: *"operator * do at beginning of an equation"* -- if you had an equation, an asterisk at the beginning of the equation would look like `* x = y`. (An equation includes an equals sign, hence the name, so the beginning is before the equals sign.) This is not what you are asking about. A mathematical equation like `x = * y` has the asterisk at the beginning of one side of the equation, also known as an expression. Conveniently, this term carries over to comp sci. The scenario you are asking about involves an asterisk at the beginning of an **expression**, not the beginning of an equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `x = * y`, `y` is most likely a *pointer* to something, in which case `*` is used to *dereference* the pointer, giving you a reference to the object to which `y` points and `x = *y;` copy assigns that value to `x`.

Example:

```cpp
int val = 10;
int* y = &val; // y is now pointing at val
int x;

x = *y;        // the space after `*` doesn't matter
```

After this, `x` has the value `10`.

Another option is that `y` is an instance of a type for which `operator*` is overloaded. Example:

```cpp
struct foo {
    int operator*() const { return 123; }
};

int main() {
    foo y;
    int x;
    x = *y;
}
```

Here, `*y` calls the `operator*()` member function on the `foo` instance `y` which returns `123`, which is what gets assigned to `x`.

---

> the order and spaces make me think it's different than the *= operator or *y pointer.

The spaces don't matter. `* y` and `*y` are the same thing, but it is indeed different from `*=`, which is the *multiply and assign* operator. Example:

```
int x = 2;
int y = 3;
x *= y;     // logically the same as `x = x * y;`
```

After this, `x` would be `6`.

---

Combining dereferencing and the *mutiply and assign* operator while using a non-idiomatic placement of spaces can certainly produce some confusing looking code:

```cpp
int val = 10;
int* y = &val;
int x = 2;

x *=* y;     // `x = x * (*y)`  =>  `x = 2 * 10`
```